# Visualizing $E=Y\cap G$ geometrically for some open set $G\subset X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I came  across this theorem(2.30) in Rudin's text on analysis.
Suppose $Y\subset X$. A subset  $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to $Y$ if and only if $E=Y\cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of $X$.
(A set $E\subset Y$ is  open  relative to $Y$ when for every $p\in E$, there is an $r_p>0$ such that $q\in Y$ and $d(p, q)<r_p$ implies $q\in E$.)

I can understand the proof he has provided. He has tried to construct such a $G$ by defining open sets $V_p$ as follows: $V_p=\{q\in X|d(p,q)\}<r_p$ and has taken $G= \cup_{p\in E}V_p$ which is good enough to prove that $E\subset G\cap Y$.

But I am still unable to understand the geometric intuition behind this; in particular, what is the geometric  motivation behind such a construction? I am interested in a better way to visualize this which will allow me to construct a formal proof by looking at the picture.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this construction you should see it in the general context of constructing new topological spaces from old ones. In the following picture (taken from [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html))

[image: subspace]

we have the big space $X=\mathbb R^2$, the usual plane, and the subset $A$, which is the circle. You also see a point $P$ on the circle and the intersection of a neighbourhood of $P$ with the circle. This "square""neighbourhood would be given by a distance if the distance used on the plane is given by the norm $||(x,y)||=\max(|x|,|y|)$. The picture also shows a point $Q$ on $A$ and an open set in $X$ whose intersection with $A$ is not a neighbourhood of $Q$.

Drawing a picture of this type should give you a key idea of the proof which you have written out.